# How to skip lines based on a criteria while loading a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to load a csv file with D3.js but I want to skip some lines based on some criteria When I apply `filter()` it says no such function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var dataSet = d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(d) 
      {
       // trying to skip the line based on the below condition
       if (d.year < 1900)
       {
          //skip loading, not sure what should I return
          return false;
        }
       else
       return {
         
          name: d.name,
          year: d.year,
          average_rating: d.average_rating,
          user_rated: d.user_rated
       };
     })
```

data.csv:

```
name,year,average_rating,users_rated
King of Tokyo,2011,7.23048,48611
Love Letter,2012,7.25253,47014
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Worked just fine as:

```
const dataSet = d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(d) 
          {
           // skips all the lines where d.year >= 1900 condition
           if (d.year >= 1900){
              return {             
              name: d.name,
              year: d.year,
              average_rating: d.average_rating,
              user_rated: d.user_rated
               }
            };
         }).then(function(d){

          //some more data manipulation
          // d.field = +d.field;
          
         })
         .catch(function(error) 
         {
            console.log(error);
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to *skip lines* when loading the CSV. So, if your CSV has 1MB but only a couple of lines fit the criteria, you'll still have to load the whole 1MB. However, despite you having *"skip loading"* in your question it seems to me that you just want to *filter* the parsed CSV. If that's correct, you can either use a regular filter or, as you're trying to do in your question, you can use a *row conversion* function.

In that case just check the year: you return the whole object if it fits the criterion or, otherwise, return `null`. Check this simple demo:

```js
const csv = `name,year
foo,1300
bar,1800,
baz,2200`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d => +d.year < 1900 ? d : null);

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the fact that numbers are parsed as strings, hence the `+d.year`.

Comment: Gerardo Furtado: ["There is no way to skip lines when loading the CSV. So, if your CSV has 1MB but only a couple of lines fit the criteria, you'll still have to load the whole 1MB"]   

- Interesting comment. I used the code below applying the "if-else" statement. The size of the object varies accordingly to the criteria.  Any reference to your statement?  

 Object.keys(dataSet).length

Comment: @GenciYmeri XHR or Fetch cannot load part of a file.

Comment: I think the question was what portion of the loaded file can be assigned at the DOM object in the first place. So it is possible to be filtered, rather than assigning the entire data of the file to an object, and only then redo the filtering in a second loop.  I did a few tests with Object.keys(dataSet).length and that seems to support the case - the info can be filtered without assigning all the data first. As per the file itself, most likely is fully loaded.